# What could be the reason-s for a exe not to load after a Dnspy modification to a DLL

Tags: dll, dnspy

After modifying a method of a DLL with Dnspy, the related EXE won't start.

What could be the reason for it not starting?

Here's what I did:

1. I modified a method from a DLL with Dnspy using edit Method (C#).
2. Compiled.
3. Saved the DLL using Save All with Shared Method Bodies ticked
   and  Mixed-Mode module ticked.

Notes:

The saved DLL is 5.29MB vs 4.86MB before saving.

I saved it from inside a duplicate folder of the exe install folder with all other dlls etc.

Comment: The cause could be integrity checks performed by the executable (checksums, fingerprinting, static max module size, whatever) which make loading the edited DLL impossible. In that case you need to patch up the executable too.